# Is there a single program version of inetd?

Tags: services, inetd

`inetd` can make several  programs with stdin input and stdout output work like programs with input and output from and to sockets, and monitor their listening sockets simultaneously.

Is there a simpler program than `inetd` which just works for a single program: make a single program with stdin input and stdout output work like a program with input and output from and to sockets?

Thanks.

Comment: If your Linux distribution is using systemd, then systemd can do that all for you (in other words, you don't need any extra software), simply by configuring a [socket unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) and a corresponding service unit to run your program.

Answer (score 16):

[Nmap’s Ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/) can do this, with its `-c` or `-e` options:

```
nc -l -c bc
```

will listen on the default port (31337) and, when a connection is established, run `bc` with its standard input and output connected to the socket.

```
nc localhost 31337
```

will then connect to a “remote” `bc` and you can then enter `bc` expressions and see their result.

[`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) can do this too (thanks [Hermann](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/67507/hermann)):

```
socat tcp-listen:31337,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:bc
```

Comment: Excellent answer! You can also use `-k` to keep listening

Answer (score 11):

## There are plenty of UCSPI-TCP tools.

In the following, the server program is `./service`, 0.0.0.0 or ::0 are the host IP addresses, and 7777 is the port number.

There are also (not listed in this answer but documented in the various tool collections, q.v.) UCSPI-UNIX and UCSPI-LOCAL tools for AF_LOCAL sockets, tools for doing the same with FIFOs, UCSPI-SSL tools for TLS/TCP sockets, and tools for Netlink sockets.

### Bernstein ucspi-tcp

In Daniel J. Bernstein's ucspi-tcp, there is `tcpserver`:

```
tcpserver -v -P -R -H -l 0 0.0.0.0 7777 \
./service
```

There are IPv6-capable enhanced versions of Bernstein ucspi-tcp such as Erwin Hoffman's `tcpserver`:

```
tcpserver -v -P -R -H -l 0 ::0 7777 \
./service
```

### Bercot s6-networking

Laurent Bercot's s6-networking has `s6-tcpserver4`:

```
s6-tcpserver4 -v 0.0.0.0 7777 \
./service
```

and `s6-tcpserver6`:

```
s6-tcpserver6 -v ::0 7777 \
./service
```

These are shims for other s6-networking tools.

### nosh UCSPI tools

The nosh toolset has `tcp-socket-listen` and `tcp-socket-accept`:

```
tcp-socket-listen --combine4and6 :: 7777 \
tcp-socket-accept --verbose --localname 0 \
./service
```

It also has a `tcpserver` that is just a shim for the other two and that defaults several options on:

```
tcpserver -v -l 0 :: 7777 \
./service
```

### Pape ipsvd

Gerrit Pape's ipsvd has `tcpsvd`:

```
tcpsvd -v 0.0.0.0 7777 \
./service
```

### Sampson onenetd

Adam Sampson has a `onenetd`:

```
onenetd -v :: 7777 \
./service
```

## Further reading

- Protocol:

  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on the UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/UCSPI.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
  - Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). *[UNIX Client-Server Program Interface](http://cr.yp.to/proto/ucspi.txt)*.  cr.yp.to.
- toolsets:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[ucspi-tcp](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html)*.  cr.yp.to.
  - [s6-networking](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/index.html).  Laurent Bercot.  skarnet.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[nosh](http://jdebp.info/Softwares/nosh/).*  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[djbwares](http://jdebp.info/Softwares/djbwares/).*  Softwares.
  - [ipsvd](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/index.html).  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
  - [onenetd](http://offog.org/code/onenetd/).  Adam Sampson.  offog.org.
- reference manuals:

  - Daniel J. Bernstein. *[The `tcpserver` program](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html)*.  ucspi-tcp.
  - Erwin Hoffmann.  [`tcpserver`](http://fehcom.de/ipnet/ucspi-tcp6/tcpserver.html).  *ucspi-tcp6*.  fehcom.de.
  - [`s6-tcpserver4`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver4.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`s6-tcpserver6`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-networking/s6-tcpserver6.html).  Laurent Bercot.  *s6-networking*.  skarnet.org.
  - [`tcpsvd`](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html).  *ipsvd*.  Gerrit Pape.  smarden.org.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcpserver`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcpserver.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcp-socket-listen`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-listen.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcp-socket-accept`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/tcp-socket-accept.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`tcpserver`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/tcpserver.xml).  djbwares.  Softwares.

Comment: This answer would be improved by leading in with the connection between the question (loosely, "programs talking to sockets") and the terminology used in the answer ("UCSPI").  If you explain what UCSPI is, then everything else will be clearer.  Like most things djb, it's a boutique term, and not widely recognized.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the programs listed by JdeBP, [courier](http://www.courier-mta.org/) also uses a wrapper like this, called [couriertcpd](http://www.courier-mta.org/couriertcpd.html).