# Does `inetd` (and `nc`) apply only to programs written as daemons?

Tags: daemon, nc, inetd

When `inetd` makes several programs run as services, does `inetd`  require the programs necessarily written as daemons (e.g. not having a controlling terminal, no interactive input, ...)?

Or can`inetd` daemonize  nondaemon processes, similar to what `setid` can do?

By the way, same questions for `nc`, given that https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500646/674

Thanks.

Comment: At least `nc` can't required that, because it i s not able to check the code of the program. It simply run that program in a new process with the connection socket as stdin and stdout. Does this mean daemonized? That depends on your definition of daemon.

Comment: Daemonize In a way similar to `setsid`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `nc` don't call `setsid` or anything special in that new process, you might want to `strace` it.

Comment: Typically, applications designed to be executed by `inetd` should _not_ try to make themselves into daemons.  `inetd` will execute the command when an incoming connection is made, the process will run as a child of inetd, and when the session is over then it can terminate.   If 2 connections are made then `inetd` will run two copies of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, applications designed to be executed by `inetd` should *not* try to make themselves into daemons. `inetd` will execute the command when an incoming connection is made, the process will run as a child of `inetd`, and when the session is over then it can terminate.

So, for example, you *can* run `sshd` via `inetd`, but you need to pass the `-D` flag to `sshd` prevent it from becoming a daemon.

If 2 connections are made then `inetd` will run two copies of the program.